# SQL Server tells me database is in use but it isn't

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, database-backups

SQL Server keeps telling me a database is in use when I try to drop it or restore it, but when I run this metadata query:

```
select * from sys.sysprocesses 
where dbid 
  in (select database_id from sys.databases where name = 'NameOfDb')
```

It returns nothing.

Sometimes it will return 1 process which is a CHECKPOINT_QUEUE waittype.  If I try to kill that process, it won't let me (cannot kill a non-user process).

Anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried checking the close existing connections option?

Comment: You're not *in* the database you're trying to drop are you? Stupid as it sounds, you have to be in a different database when executing such commands

Comment: This question might have a better chance of getting good answers on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll just use: alter database [MyDatbase] set single_user with rollback immediate for now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There could be lots of things blocking your database. For example, if you have a query window opened on that database, it would be locked by you. Not counting external accesses, like a web application on IIS.

If you really wanna force the drop on it, check the close existing connections option or try to manually stop SQL Server's service.

Comment: Yeah, as it is I've been manually restarting the service, but obviously I can't keep doing that.  I'll try the close existing connections option.

Comment: @tuseau That option is available if you try to drop the database visually, not by command line. Sincerely, I don't know how to set that option programmatically. But if you try to drop it visually, you'll notice the checkbox. Glad I could help.

Comment: Indeed, I found that even a open query tab with in SQL Server Management Studio would prevent database from taking it off.

Comment: It's impossible that creating a new database from a backup could be in use. It's a fake error but, nonetheless, one that continually obstructs getting things done.

Answer (score 37):

i like this script. Do not struggle with killing..

```
use master

alter database xyz set single_user with rollback immediate

restore database xyz ...

alter database xyz set multi_user
```

Comment: What kind of genius solution this is.

Answer (score 22):

I was having the same issue when trying to restore a database from a backup. The solution for me was to ensure that I checked "Overrite the existing database(WITH REPLACE)" and "Close existing connections to destination database" in the Options page BEFORE doing the restore. Here is a screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: For GUI users who are more casual or infrequent users of SSMS or SQL in general knowing how to tick these options during a restore is key option

Comment: "Close existing connections to destination database" is not always available. I'm not sure why - from my observations it's always available on my local db with Simple recovery model, but is never available if I'm restoring a backup from the server which was set to Full recovery model.

Comment: It's not always available because someone at Microsoft makes bad decisions. When I want to restore a database I've already decided that any user who is connected needs to be disconnected, so blocking the restore is unwanted behavior.